# dynamic width custom select box with CSS

Tags: html, css

I need to style the select boxes in my web site something like below,

[image]

I have suceded with `html`+`css` for fix sizes as below,

```
<div><select></select></div>

div{
    background: url("select-box-background.png") no-repeat scroll right center #fff;
    height: 23px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 54px;
}
select{
    background: transparent;
    border: 0 none;
    border-radius: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1;
    padding: 3px;
    width: 78px;
    color: #78abd0;
}
```

But I can't manage to apply this for all select boxes with different width, because I have done the styles with fix width.

How to manage same thing with the dynamic width.

Comment: Don't use an image for the whole select element - only for the arrow part. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/1895476/703717

Comment: seems to be a good solution, i'll try this one and let you know the updates